# Subtract two columns in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to subtract two arrays or columns if you want with `=M64:M69-K64:K69`. Here are my two columns

```
$4.28       $4.90
$37.26      $33.87
$5.34       $5.16
$887.06     $734.70
$2.68       $2.55
$14.57      $13.51
```

I got the error `#VALUE!`

How can I subtract two columns?

Comment: You can self-answer the question, but do it in the answer space, not as an update to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(M64:M69-K64:K69)
```